# Why Multiple OrderBy consumes much time to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried Querying from Table with multiple `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP 50
  TBL_ContentsPage.NewsId,
  TBL_ContentsPage.author,
  TBL_ContentsPage.Header,
  TBL_ContentsPage.TextContent,
  TBL_ContentsPage.PostedDate,
  TBL_ContentsPage.status,
  TBLTempSettings.templateID
FROM TBL_ContentsPage
INNER JOIN TBLTempSettings
  ON TBL_ContentsPage.NewsId = TBLTempSettings.newsId
WHERE TBL_ContentsPage.mode = '1' AND TBLTempSettings.mode = '1' AND (TBLTempSettings.templateID = @templateID OR @templateID = 'all')
ORDER BY 0 + TBLTempSettings.rank DESC
```

But when I add `TBL_ContentsPage.PostedDate DESC` the query takes more than double time. `TBLTempSettings.rank` is indexed already.

Comment: An index is useless if you're performing a transformation on the column (such as here, converting to int in an ugly way). Are you able to alter the schema - could you add a computed column where `rank` is already converted to `int` and index that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort your query results, SQL Server burns CPU time.

The ***ORDER BY clause*** consumes all of the query results as fast as possible into memory in your app, and then sort.

Your application is already designed in a way that you can scale out multiple app servers to distribute CPU load, whereas your database server…is not.

The sort operations, besides using the TEMPDB system database for a temporary storage area, also add a great I/O rate to the operations.

Therefore, if you are used to seeing the Sort operator frequently in its queries and this operator has a high consumption operation, consider removing the mentioned clause. On the other hand, if you know that will always organize your query by a specific column, consider indexing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT TOP 50   c.newsId
            ,   c.author
            ,   c.Header
            ,   c.TextContent
            ,   c.PostedDate
            ,   c.status
            ,   t.templateID
FROM TBL_ContentsPage c
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM TBLTempSettings t
    WHERE t.mode = '1'
        AND (t.templateID = @templateID OR @templateID = 'all')
) t ON c.newsId = CAST(t.newsId AS INT)
WHERE c.mode = '1'
ORDER BY t.rank DESC
```

Comment: the rank column is varchar really. ( Such a design I got). Any prob with casting to int (I added 0 to column to do this)

Comment: Can you provide a `DDL` for your tables?

Comment: This much lag occurs when I add `TBL_ContentsPage.PostedDate DESC` to order by clause. When I remove this, it works very much better.

Comment: Try to change data-type (`INT [NOT NULL]`) for `newsId` column, and also, if possible, set `rank` column to `NOT NULL`.